# Finding left/right vertices to a point in a triangle in 3D

Tags: c++, math, graphics, 3d

Given a triangle in 3D and a point on one of its edges, I want to find out which of the vertices of that edge is to the left of that point, and which is to the right.

Please see the image below:

[image]

In this image, vertices `v2` and `v3` are always positioned as shown. There is also a line segment between `v3` and `v2`. The problem is with vertices `v0` and `v1`, which may be given in a swapped order. I want to find out whether `v0` is to the 'left' or 'right' of `v3` so that I can enforce `v0` to always be to its left and `v1` to always be to its right.

Since this problem is in 3D I am not sure how to efficiently compute the relative positions of the vertices. Do I first reduce this to a 2-dimensional problem (and if so, how) or is there another way?

Comment: How do you define "left" and "right?" Do you have an external viewer position?

Comment: Maybe it doesn't have to be "left" and "right" as long as v0 is the first in the sequence, and v1 the last.

Comment: That still depends on whether you're looking at the triangle from the top or from the bottom. You need some form of reference frame to be able to judge the order in the sequence.

Comment: Well I do have an external viewer position, but it can rotate around the triangle, so I don't think that is reliable. However, the triangle does have a normal vector, so maybe that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As clarified in the comments, "left" and "right" (or any other ordering of `v0` and `v1`) depends on some reference. You mentioned you know the triangle's normal vector (call it `N`) - that can be used for such a reference.

Let's say that the normal vector points towards the viewer in your example image. Then, compute the vector product of `v2 - v3` and `v0 - v3`. This will either point to the same half-space as the normal (meaning `v0` is "to the left"), or to the opposite half-space (meaning `v0` is "to the right").

Since `N` is normal to the triangle's plane, a vector `v` points to the same half-space if the angle between `v` and `N` is less than 90 degrees; in other words, if the dot product of `v` and `N` is positive.

These together give you the ordering criterion you need.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the solution. After reading Raxvan's comment, I figured something like this could be done.

Answer (score 1):

in 3d the "left" and "right" is dependent to the position of the observer (lets call this position `P` ). Imagine that you are viewing that triangle from the other side , then the left and right are reversed. So viewing from position P you need to determine if the vertices are clockwise or anti-clockwise.

To do that you can compute this:

```
N = normalize( cross( v0 - v2, v1 - v2 ) );
PV = normalzie( P - v2 );
if( dot( PV, N ) > 0.0 )
{
    //anticlockwise , so you are viewing the picture like in your drawing, then v0 is on the left of vector v3v2, and v1 is on the right
}
else
{
    //clockwise, v0 is on the right
}
```

Note that if `dot` product is almost/or 0 then `P` is on the same plane as your triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Find the cross product of vectors v2-v3 and v1-v2. Deduce the direction from the direction of the product.

Whether the vector is pointing upwards from the plane or downward.

This is if I have correctly understood your definition of right and left.